# CakePHP add model association into database table

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

I'm new to CakePHP and English isn't my first language so I apologize if my question isn't clear. Anyway, I have two models: *Developer* and *Game*.

```
<?php
class Developer extends AppModel
{
    var $name = 'Developer';
    var $belongsTo = array('Game');
}
?>
```

and

```
<?php
class Game extends AppModel
{
    var $name = 'Game';
    var $hasMany = array('Developer');
}
?>
```

How would I be able to add a new row in the table developer_games that only has game_id and developer_id fields that indicates there is a relationship between a game and a developer without actually knowing the id's of the game and developer because they're created at the same time. I thought CakePHP was able to do this for me but it wouldn't add a new row in the developer_games table. Would I have to retrieve the 'id' fields of the Game and Developer after saving data then save the relationship model data to the developer_games table manually afterwards?

Here's the code I use to add a new game and developer to the database:

```
$data = $this->Game->saveAll(array(
    'Game' => array(
        'game_id' => $data['GameId'],
        'game_name' => $data['GameName'],
    ),
    'Developer' => array(
        'Developer' => array(
            'username' => $_POST['dev_username'],
            'password_hash' => $_POST['dev_password'],
        ),
    ),
));
$this->Game->saveAll($data);
```

If I wasn't clear with something, let me know and I'll clarify. I've been struggling with this problem for a long time, so I'll appreciate any help I can get. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I dont misunderstood, Game-Developer relationships in many-to-many in logical diagram, then it should be [Game]-1:N-[Assignment]-N:1-[Developer]
Assignment here is your "developer_games" table, I suggest you rename the table for convenient

According to your scenario, recommended implementation in CakePHP would be 3 model classes.

```
<?php
class Developer extends AppModel
{
    var $name = 'Developer';
    var $hasMany = array('Assignment');
}
?>

<?php
class Game extends AppModel
{
    var $name = 'Game';
    var $hasMany = array('Assignment');
}
?>

<?php
class Assignment extends AppModel
{
    var $name = 'Assignment';
    var $belongsTo = array('Game','Developer');
}
?>
```

Here is the code to add new Assignment

```
//retrieved submitted data --> $data
$data = $this->data;

// this is for the case you want to insert into 3 tables at a same time
$newGame = $this->Game->create();
$newGame = array(
    'Game'=> array(
        'name' => $data['Game']['name']
    )
);
$this->Game->save($newGame);
$newGameId = $this->Game->getLastInsertId();

$newDev = $this->Developer->create();
$newDev = array(
    'Developer'=> array(
        'name' => $data['Developer']['name']
    )
);
$this->Developer->save($newDev);
$newDevId = $this->Developer->getLastInsertId();

/**
* or if you already have Game Id, and Developer Id, then just load it on, and 
* put it in the statement below, to create a new Assignment
**/
$newAssignment = $this->Assignment->create();
$newAssignment = array(
    'Assignment' => array(
        'game_id' => $newGameId,
        'developer_id' => $newDevId,
    )
);
$this->Assignment->save($newAssignment);
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I wanted! But, I keep getting this strange error: "Notice (8): Undefined index: id [CORE\cake\libs\model\model.php, line 1329]". Do you have any idea why this error shows up? I believe it has to do with the getLastInsertId function.

Comment: Nevermind, solved it. The assignments table needed an 'id' field.

Comment: English isnt my native language also, there are some stupid grammar errors in my writing, hope you guys dont mind

Comment: CakePHP has a "hasAndBelongsToMany"-relationship-type. Why don't use that? It fits exactly into the wanted scenario!

Answer (score 0):

Please have a read on this: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1044/hasAndBelongsToMany-HABTM
"hasAndBelongsToMany" is the relationship you want. Cake takes care about the associations and you don't need a model for the join table.

Comment: Hmm, I've tried using that before but to no avail. I'll attempt once again and I'll get back to you.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to save data. The cookbook is somewhat vague and confusing considering I'm not actually using a form directly.